# How to change google maps center using the received json coordinates?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I am using google maps api to show locations a user visited, the coordinates of those locations i receive in json format. I am trying to make the center of the map to be the first location which will be the first set of coordinates in the json. But it does not seem to work. Here is my code-

```
var username = "<%= session.getAttribute("Member").toString() %>";
var path = [];
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8082/letstravel/location/"+username;

function getJson() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(myArr);
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {
    var i;
    center = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(arr[0].latitude), parseFloat(arr[0].longitude));
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(arr[i].latitude), parseFloat(arr[i].longitude)));
    }
}


function initMap() {
    getJson();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });

    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: path,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

There is something wrong with the code as the map is not showing, it only works if i specify a center like this

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
```

This is a json response example

```
[{"latitude":28.648036,"longitude":77.2326533,"sos":0},{"latitude":28.646096,"longitude":77.183385,"sos":0},{"latitude":28.648333,"longitude":77.213455,"sos":1},{"latitude":28.640015,"longitude":77.168119,"sos":0},{"latitude":28.644299,"longitude":77.162207,"sos":0}]
```

How do i make the center change for every user using the json i receive. Please help.

Comment: could you post also a representative example of `xmlhttp.responseText`?

Comment: Do you mean json response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call getJson() from your initMap function, its not going to wait around for a response. Upon success from your AJAX call you need to then call the map initiation logic.

Try something like this:

```
var username = "<%= session.getAttribute("Member").toString() %>";
var path = [];
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);

var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8082/letstravel/location/"+username;

StartMapProcess();

function StartMapProcess() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            myFunction(myArr);
            initMap();
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(arr) {
    var i;
    center = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(arr[0].latitude), parseFloat(arr[0].longitude));
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(arr[i].latitude), parseFloat(arr[i].longitude)));
    }
}


function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });

    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: path,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: You mean i should call the initMap function from getJson() ?

Comment: Yes - from within the success block, right after myFunction(myArr);

Comment: So i did what you said, but now instead of nothing i am getting a greyish space instead of the map.